# Browser Update Banner button

Tags: javascript, button, banner

I am adding a browser update banner to a website. I'm taking the JS code from https://browser-update.org/. The banner generate fine, but what I'm trying to do is add a third button next to the "ignore" button and link it to a separate page. I tried to add a div class to the JS but that didn't work. Is adding a third button linked to a page something that can be done? I'm clearly not JS saavy.

Answer (score 0):

do you have a codepen version of it. Can you replicate the issue? I will try to help. Based on my own understanding you want to add a button on the update banner code. The code provided by browser update banner is a single javascript code. I think it is under an iframe or what that's why you can't inject a code in it. My opinion you need to create a seperate div outside the javascript code and float it above the layer of the banner and place it manually beside the ignore button but that one has many step to do. But it will solve your issue. If you can replicate it I will help you in achieving it.

Comment: They actually provide some customizations here: https://browser-update.org/customize.html   

I was able to just switch out the text to something more custom. But now I need to turn one of the words into a link, I know that can't be done in JS. Anyway to make this happen?

My current code: 
https://jsfiddle.net/uthqv9wp/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it. Added this to the script:
text: 'Your web browser ({brow_name}) is out of date. click here to learn more'
};